# How to localize or translate webforms?

Tags: webforms

I have installed the [Webform Localization](http://drupal.org/project/webform_localization) module but it's unstable and doesn't seem to work yet (it's in dev)

Ideally, I would like to replicate the behavior of other content types: create a new node that is linked to the original so the user can switch.

Any thoughts or similar experience?